# Error in exporting to PDF document using PHP from MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

my code is generating the pdf document file but the output in PDF is printed as variable only not the value in the database. Can someone look whats the problem?

```
require('fpdf.php');

    mysql_connect("localhost","user","pwd") or die("Couldn't connect!");
    mysql_select_db("db_name") or die("Couldn't find db");

$pdf=new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();

$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sold WHERE imei = '87712839712893'");

while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($data))
{
    $pdf->SetFont('arial','B',10);
    $pdf->Cell(40,40,'$result["saledate"]');
    $pdf->SetFont('arial','B',30);
    $pdf->Cell(40,10,'$result["sellingprice"]');
}

// I don't know if the pdf Cell() command numeric arguments need to change or not. If they do, change them.

$pdf->Output();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using single quotes:

```
$pdf->Cell(40,40,'$result["saledate"]');
```

leading to the variables not getting parsed.

Use double quotes instead.

Comment: or don't put any quotes around $result["saledate"]

Comment: thanks for the help but if I just remove single quotes the result is as desired. Anyways thanks for the help